# sanskrit mantras and reading doubt?

Tags: mantras, sanskrit, hymn

i am reading a book and some sanskrit mantras in it is written as 'om namo bhagvate 2 kruna 2 avataram .' what does this 2 means.Thus that mean i have to read the word twice??

Comment: Or it could be a footnote, and the explanation present at the bottom of the page. Of course, you already checked this, Just saying

Comment: in this books thee are many mantras some has 2 written in between.

Comment: Which book? Can you post screenshot of that page or online link?

Comment: Yes i will post after some time.

Answer (score 1):

2 after a word refers to chanting it 2 times.In future if you deal with such kind off numbers between sankrit hymns means repeating that word that number of times.